# MySQL AES_ENCRYPT string key length

Tags: aes, mysql

In MySQL there are builtin `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` functions which take the form of:

```
AES_ENCRYPT(str, key_str)
```

What length is required for the `key_str` argument? Can it be variable? What is the minimum and maximum string key lengths?

Answer (score 5):

MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT` function is insecure by default, as it uses [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_(ECB)) unless configured otherwise. [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) provides an example of how to use CBC mode with a 256 bit key (though their example of a key is terrible):

> ```
> mysql> SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
> mysql> SET @key_str = SHA2('My secret passphrase',512);
> mysql> SET @init_vector = RANDOM_BYTES(16);
> mysql> SET @crypt_str = AES_ENCRYPT('text',@key_str,@init_vector);
> mysql> SELECT AES_DECRYPT(@crypt_str,@key_str,@init_vector);
> ```

What key length you want to use depends on what [`block_encryption_mode`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode) you configure. Supported key lengths are 128, 192, and 256 (which also happen to be the only key lengths allowed by AES).

It can be seen [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/mysql-8.0.12/mysys_ssl/my_aes.cc#L55) that if the provided key is too small it will be null-padded (due to the `memset`), and if it is too large it will xor the extra bytes with the first `key_size` bytes (e.g. if the key size is 4 bytes and the provided key is 12345678, it will xor 5678 with 1234 and use the result as the key). For best security you should use a random key of the size you configure AES to use. For AES-128 you want a 128 bit random key, or 32 hex characters:

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('text', UNHEX('6133C3D40B2BF9267E85ED0C2FDDC686'), @init_vector);
```

For AES-256 you want a 256 bit random key, which is 64 hex characters:

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('text', UNHEX('08672D4D2424CFE10E5221BF2EB8409C57431B30B55D6AE2D167E5F9682EF711'), @init_vector);
```

The MySQL documentation fails to note that the IV (initialization vector) **must not** be reused for multiple encryptions, and of course the IV must be stored to allow for decryption.

It should also be noted that none of the encryption modes that MySQL 
supports provide [authenticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication), and of the supported modes, ECB is terrible and CBC, CFB, and OFB are all [malleable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malleability_(cryptography)).

Comment: How to keep @key_str in safe place so that unauthorized user can't have access?

Answer (score 0):

**Variable Key Length:**

Yes, you can use different key length if you are going to use multiple keys. And the key size depends on type of data.

For instance, [NSA](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/programs/suiteb_cryptography/) considers 128 bit keys good enough only for data with SECRET designation. For TOP SECRET though, it requires 256 bit keys. The European Network of Excellence in Cryptology report also recommends 128 bit keys for long term protection, but says 256 bit keys are the only good protection against quantum computers.

**Key Sizes:**

[AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher) supports three different key sizes. If you specify smaller key then it would be automatically padded by AES.

1. 128 bits
2. 192 bits
3. 256 bits

The standard 128 bit keys are used in [AES_Encrypt()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) and [AES_Decrypt()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt). However you can extend it to 256.

Please make sure you select field type as binary because `AES_ENCRYPT()` encrypts a string and returns a binary string. `AES_DECRYPT()` decrypts the encrypted string and returns the original string.

**Sample Code:**

**Table:**

```
CREATE  TABLE `user` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `first_name` VARBINARY(100) NULL ,
  `address` VARBINARY(200) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

**Insert statement with encryption function:**

```
INSERT into user (first_name, address) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('John', 'usa2018'), AES_ENCRYPT('Obama', 'usa2019'));
```

**Select statement with decryption function:**

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(first_name, 'usa2018'), AES_DECRYPT(address, 'usa2019') from user;
```

Comment: So if I use a `key_str` that is 48 characters does this cause any problems?

Comment: The keys sizes are [more due to regulation](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6049/151903) than actual security, though 256 bit keys _may_ become useful once quantum computers become large and fast enough.

Comment: You say you can extend the key size to 256 bits, but you don't describe how. If you just specify a longer key it will xor bits 129-256 with bits 1-128 and use the resulting 128 bit key.